# Initializing list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to initialize a list of numpy arrays in the following way

```
import numpy as np
sol=[np.zeros(5)]*4
```

But when I try to modify one of the list members like this,

```
sol[0][2:4]=[1,1]
```

It changes all the list members instead of only the first one

```
[array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.])]
```

I guess it is old story about mutable and inmutable objects, but I simply don't know how to solve it.

I tried using copy and deepcopy, but not successful.

Sorry if it is duplicated entry, but I couldn't find any similar question

Thanks

Comment: You need to create *a separate `array`* each time: `sol = [np.zeros(5) for _ in range(4)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and the answer is:

```
np.zeros((4, 5))
```

and to explain the point about mutable objects. when you do this:

```
[np.zeros(5)] * 4
```

it's functionally the equivalent of this:

```
a = np.zeros(5)
[a, a, a, a]
```

Comment: Dammit!! i guess I am tired. Thanks for the mutable explanation.

Comment: remember you can always check an object's id with function `id`. if those numbers are the same, then it's the same object.